# How to load entirely different ViewController in a Master-Detail app?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, ios5

I have a Master-Detail app and I want to load a new view on the click of rows in Master. If I select row-1, the view is different, and on selection of a different row, new view is presented in Detail portion. How can I achieve this thing?

I am doing something like this. The issue is - If I select any of these 2 rows for the first time, the view actually changes. But again when I click on the other row, it does not change.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if(indexPath.row==0){


    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 

    TwitterTweetViewController *detailView=(TwitterTweetViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwitterDetailView"];

    self.splitViewController.mainViewController = detailView;
    [self.splitViewController.mainViewController viewDidLoad];
    [self.splitViewController viewDidLoad];

}


if(indexPath.row == 1)
{

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil]; 

    TwitterDetailViewController *detailView=(TwitterDetailViewController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"TwitterDetailView"];

    self.splitViewController.mainViewController = detailView;
    [self.splitViewController.mainViewController viewDidLoad];
    [self.splitViewController viewDidLoad];

}
```

}

What should I do in order to change the view on selecting these rows?

Comment: Is this what you're looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272244/uisplitviewcontroller-on-ipad-with-storyboards

Answer (score 0):

There is a great method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Use it. It is called right after the click has been made on a cell. You can put some check in there. Short example:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    SomeViewController *svc = [[SomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SomeViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc];
  } else if (indexPath.row > 0 && indexPath.row < 5) {
    SomeOtherViewController *sovc = [[SomeOtherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"SomeOtherViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:sovc];
  } else {
    AnotherViewController *avc = [[AnotherViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"AnotherViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:avc];
  }
  //some other code if needed
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Getting this error - 


2012-05-14 13:56:45.232 SpltiView With Views[26907:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/nihal/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/9D894362-800E-4BE1-BE2B-2F7E2C3DB8A3/SpltiView With Views.app> (loaded)' with name 'NewViewController''
*** First throw call stack:

terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: and since the master-detail has already defined a navigation controller for the default detail view controller - do you think using the [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc] would work?

Comment: @NihalSharma sorry, didn't see that it was for iPad

Answer (score 0):

You can create an enum of your view controllers as :-

```
enum MyViewControllers
{
viewcontroller1
viewcontroller2
viewcontroller3
}
```

The constatns in enum would correspond to your viewcontrollers for each indexPAth.

and then in the delegate method of UITAbleVIew didSelectRowAtIndexPath: , use switch case :-

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath 
    {
    switch(indexPath.row)
{
    case 1:
          Load view1
          break;
    case 2:
          Load view2
          break;
    case 3:
          Load view3
          break;     .
         .
         so on.
    }
}
```

Or in case of different NavigationControllers (as in iPad )you will have to  pass data using delegates and protocol.Define the protocol in rootViewController and then set its delegate in the detail(Where you want to push the viewcontroller)

somethinglike :-

```
@protocol SendSelectedINdexDelegate
{
@required
-(void)sendTheIndex:(NSNumber)number.
@end
```

in interface

```
id <SendSelectedINdexDelegate> delegateSend
```

set its property:-

```
@property (nonatomic) id delegateSend;
```

in .m

```
@synthesize delegateSend
```

and in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
[self delegate]sendTheIndex:indexPath.row];

}
```

At the receiving controller 
conform to protocol
and set

```
rootview.delegateSend=self;
```

and implement the method of protocol;

```
-(void)sendTheIndex:(NSNumber)number
{
//nsnumber is your index perform operation based on this.
}
```

Comment: I do not think it will work. Please suggest something other than this.

Comment: [self delegate]sendTheIndex:indexPath.row];
should read:
[[self delegateSend]sendTheIndex:indexPath.row];
but then you´ll have an incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending NSInteger to a NSNumber parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Take care that if you are using ARC,it forbids synth of a property with unspecified ownership attribute( in .m @synthesize delegateSend).