# iPad UISplitviewControllers with Storyboards ands Cocos2d multiple scene error

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uistoryboard

I have a UISplitviewController app that's structured like the picture in this question:

[UISplitViewController on iPad with Storyboards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272244/uisplitviewcontroller-on-ipad-with-storyboards)

When I click on either Game #1 or Game #2, their respective game run.
However, if I click on the second game (either #1 or #2), I get this
error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'You can't run an scene
if another Scene is running. Use replaceScene or pushScene instead'
```

How can I check to see if there's already an existing Cocos2d scene
and replace it when the second game is clicked?  Ideally, I think I should keep both games running so
the user can click back to the other game.  Is
this possible?

I tried to simply replace this line: [director runWithScene:scene];

with this line:  [director replaceScene:scene];

Unfortunately, I get an error CCTextureAtlas.m, in method:

-(void) drawNumberOfQuads: (NSUInteger) n fromIndex: (NSUInteger) start {...}

[image]

[Update]

I think I might need to stop the scene so everything is cleaned up properly.  When I click on my Help screen, for example, my controller's viewWillDisappear gets called.  This does not happen when switching between Cocos2d view controllers.

---

After following these [instructions](http://fidgetware.com/Tutorials/page15/page15.html), and only creating the EAGLView once, I almost have it working, but I get a black screen for the second scene.  Note that I do briefly see the new scene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I check to see if there's already an existing Cocos2d scene
>   and replace it when the second game is clicked?

```
if ([[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene] == nil) {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:sceneToRun];
    } else {
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:sceneToRun];
    }
```

Comment: This gives the same error that I got when I tried to replace the scene.  I included a picture.  Maybe it's an ARC issue?  I think I have Cocos2d 1.1 beta.

Comment: Do you do anything else to handle multiple scenes, like only creating the EAGLView once?  See my updates.  Thanks.